# very important features, but rarely input

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataframe, feature-scaling

The features are of capital gain and capital loss, but very small amounts of people have one or the other. As far as I can see it may not signify any great difference, though I'm not sure how I would go about even normalising or whatnot these features:

```
     age        wgt       sex   gain        loss         hpw        
0   0.379310    0.119825    1   2174           0         -0.078664          
1   0.568966    0.131898    1   0              0         -2.327679          
2   0.362069    0.407596    1   0              0         -0.078664
```

The gain can skyrocket to 100,000 and that is definitely of significance considering I'm predicting whether someone will make  over $50k, though they occur at such a small rate, close to 3-5% that I'm not sure how I could go about implementing them. I doubt imputing data would be a good idea considering just about everyone is on 0 for both results.

Also to note is I have 15 columns total (many more with get_dummies()).

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking..

Comment: @Mark.F asking how I should approach this data, which if used correctly, could be used to tell the machine whether or not something is 100% possibility, though also considering it only occurs in 3-5% of rows, perhaps it is useless?

Comment: This question could definitely be improved: Start with your goal, then list the data in birds eye. Next your idea's, then the question, finally add detailed data or functions.

Comment: @S van Balen my goal is max accuracy. Not sure what you mean by birds eye (sorry I'm new to programming), my idea was to come here and ask because I have a lack of ideas, my only idea at the moment is to drop the columns, which is fine but my goal is max accuracy. Question is stated clearly I would have thought, what do I do with these 2 columns. Would you like all the data? I'm not looking for a completed answer, just to push me in the right direction. What functions would you want? All I've provided is a dataset, didn't realise datascience was so focused on the coding aspect.

Answer (score 1):

A tree-based model, especially one that allows missing data in the input, seems a good choice: the tree(s) can split large capital gains out (presumably separating a nearly pure node from the rest).

Also consider something more basic: just hard-code an exception for those with large gains, and model for the rest.